# ArangoDB Fox syntax error declaring schema argument

Tags: joi, arangodb-foxx

I have declared a JOI schema/bean and cannot use that definition when declaring another schema/bean?

I get a syntax error on "arg: joi.object.schema(TestBean).required()" but can declare an array using a schema like: "argArray: joi.array().items(TestBean).required()"

```
const TestBean = joi.object().required().keys({
  member1: joi.array().items(joi.string().required()),
  member2: joi.number().required()
}).unknown(); // allow additional attributes

const BeanMethodDocument = joi.object().required().keys({
  arg: joi.object.schema(TestBean).required(),
  argArray: joi.array().items(TestBean).required(),
  option: joi.string().valid('Empty','Full','HalfFull','HalfEmpty')
});
```

I am expecting that I can use pre-defined declarations of schemas.
I just need the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the function call on `joi.object`.

```
const BeanMethodDocument = joi.object().required().keys({
    arg: joi.object().schema(TestBean).required(),
    // ------------^
    argArray: joi.array().items(TestBean).required(),
    option: joi.string().valid('Empty','Full','HalfFull','HalfEmpty')
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it. The fact that is compiled in webstorm threw me off.